# "Но ох как хочется, чтобы давали комментарии с объяснением ошибок" (за минусование вопроса/ответа)

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Господа модераторы, да за чем же дело стало?!

На Большом Вопросе (куда я уже направляла вас - за здоровыми заимствованиями) делается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

трус, не желающий получать ответные минусы от огорчённого/озлобленного сминусованного, имеет право выступить "в режиме инкогнито" (сайтом он защищён, его не вычислить), человек принципиальный даёт коммент минусу от своего имени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ВОПРОС:** Почему бы нам (вам) не использовать накопленный коллегами опыт?

Answer (score 5):

У нас на StackOverflow тоже периодически эту тему поднимают:

- [Вопрос по решению кнопки минус на сайте Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3144/15479).
- [Настаивать на оставлении комментария при голосовании против вопроса с репутацией 0](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4013/15479).
- [Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/15479).

И на SOen: [Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/1991579).

**TL;DR:** этого не будет, так как такова официальная позиция SE.

По мелочи:

1. Один плюс > 5 минусов. Так что, в целом, достаточно хотя бы 1 плюса. Если же на вашем сообщении больше 5 минусов, то с ним явно что-то не так.
2. Нельзя принуждать людей оставлять сообщение при голосе против. А если не принуждать, то никто не будет ничего писать в этой форме. Те, кто хочет помочь, пишут в комментариях.
3. Если принуждать оставлять отзыв при голосе против, то количество минусов упадёт, что негативно скажется на качестве сайта.